# STM32 HAL I2C and MLX90621

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am working on a project using an STM32F4 nucleo board and a MLX90621 device. 
I have a problem regarding the communication between the two using the HAL I2C library.

The EEPROM has two devices inside, an EEPROM and the IR thermal device itself. 
Using the HAL library with the I2C implementation, I can read the EEPROM perfectly but I cannot read the device itself. I checked with the oscilloscope and the device does not acknowledge when I want to read it. What might be the cause?

I will attach some oscilloscope capture images below and how should they look from the datasheet. 
Reading whole frame:
[image: ReadIR_Real]
[image]

Lack of acknowledge:[image]

Comment: Can you improve the signal integrity so there is less crosstalk from SCL to SDA?  Is it excessive 10:1 probe ground length of poor GND or actual crosstalk?

Comment: I am using just one ground for both oscilloscope probe so I think that might be the problem. However, there is something else going on here. When I communicate to the EEPROM, all is good, where the Question Mark is in picture, I have an ACK. I can also see that the device is trying to ACK (I think, because it is trying to go LOW for a moment there) but for some reason it doesn't until the next clock (when it is too late).

Comment: Is Signal integrity that same at both chips?  Dont use a ground clip but solder two pins to use probe tip (clip removed) and barrel and hold with tape.  What kind of wire to target? twisted pairs or loose wire?

Comment: The thing is that both chips are in the same IC package, I just change the address to communicate with one or the other.

Comment: OK I did not analyze the address bits , can you clean up signals with probe method I suggested? what kind of cable? how long ?  Cat5? I assume SWD port?

Comment: no matter... are U using 1k8 pullup? for best performance

Comment: Since SCL is on slow rising edge, signal integrity ought to be improved meanwhile fast falling edge has cross talk

Comment: I will update tomorrow with better signals as it is late now. I managed to get a much cleaner output by using a lower transfer speed (maybe the pull-up resistors I am using are too low considering the added capacitance of the probes and the fact that I am using a prototype board at the moment) and connecting both probe grounds.

Comment: Either way, the problem I think is at the transfer. When comparing my result to the ideal signal in the datasheet there is a major difference. At the transmit sequence using HAL I2C (W60, 02, 00, 04, 40) there is a STOP and a START (where the clock is streched, can be easy seen in second picture), in the datasheet there is only a (re)START. Could this affect the ability of the slave to ACK? Strange enough, the EEPROM is not affected by this.

Comment: What is wire capacitance or type and length???? 3rd time asking

Comment: Wire length is about 10cm. I think the problem is somewhere else as even after using a clock of 10kHz and getting a crisp signal on the oscilloscope, the result is the same.

Comment: There should be no STOP between write address phase and read phase, only extra START. I think this is your problem.

Comment: Try all READ commands then and see if it is comm error or code error... also https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to I2C specifications, when so-called "combined format" is used,

[image]

there should be "repeated START" in between configuration stage (internal start and stop addresses, and the number of bytes to read) and READ function, but no STOP.

When the interface encounters STOP, it "forgets" the submitted read parameters, so the next stand-alone READ doesn't know where to read from, and NAKs.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Modifying the HAL I2C library (specifically, the Mem_Read() function, to take more parameters than just memory location) resulted in a fix. Also, the reason why I could read the EEPROM was that you can read it whole (starting from 0x00) without transmitting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but I can tell from a lot of my own mistakes with I2C that if a slave does not ACK a request, then it's almost always because the I2C slave address is not proper. Please be aware of the fact that the last bit of the first address byte is the R/W bit and often you have to shift the address from the datasheet one bit to the left prior to putting it on the bus.

Comment: Thank you for your input! The address is fine, it is 0x60 as it can be seen in the oscilloscope data (plus the read bit is set). I have left-aligned the address as the HAL library requests and the R/W bit is automatically set. I think I will have to bit bang this.